# Level-order in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, iteration

I have a structure for a tree and I want to print the tree by levels.

```
data Tree a = Nd a [Tree a] deriving Show
type Nd = String
tree = Nd "a" [Nd "b" [Nd "c" [],
                       Nd "g" [Nd "h" [],
                               Nd "i" [],
                               Nd "j" [],
                               Nd "k" []]],
               Nd "d" [Nd "f" []],
               Nd "e" [Nd "l" [Nd "n" [Nd "o" []]],
                       Nd "m" []]]
preorder (Nd x ts) = x : concatMap preorder ts
postorder (Nd x ts) = (concatMap postorder ts) ++ [x]
```

But how to do it by levels? "levels tree" should print ["a", "bde", "cgflm", "hijkn", "o"].
I think that "iterate" would be suitable function for the purpose, but I cannot come up with a solution how to use it. Would you help me, please?

Comment: You don't need the `type Nd = String`. It doesn't do anything in your code, since you never use the type Nd (you do use the data constructor Nd of type tree, but that's entirely unrelated).

Comment: I don't think you want the result in the form shown: It concatenates data from adjacent nodes in a way that a) doesn't work if a isn't a list type, and b) loses information about the traversal. Consider this tree: Nd "a" [Nd "bde" [Nd "cgflm" [Nd "hijkn" [Nd "o" []]]]] -- it would bring the same result as you asked for. In order to not fall into this trap, use characters ('a') or numbers as the node values in your example tree. That will keep your solutions nicely general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to compute the levels for all of the subtrees and zip them all together after the root:

```
levels :: Tree [a] -> [[a]]
levels (Nd a bs) = a : foldr (zipWith' (++)) [] (map levels bs)
```

Sadly, `zipWith` doesn't do the right thing, so we can instead use:

```
zipWith' f xs [] = xs
zipWith' f [] xs = xs
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

Update: there is some concern (which I agree with) that what you originally asked is a little weird as it's not a generic breadth-first tree to list convertor. What you probably really want is to concat the result of:

```
levels' (Nd a bs) = [a] : foldr (zipWith' (++)) [] (map levels' bs)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I guess the reason Haskell doesn't have your variant of zipWith, which doesn't stop at the smaller list, is that it only makes sense for f of type a->a->a. You *could* write it using just zipWith, as ` levels (Nd a bs) = a : foldr (zipWith (++)) (repeat []) (map levels bs) ` and using ` takeWhile (not.null) $ levels tree `, but that's probably just silly. :-)

Comment: You could write a version of `zipWith'` that works with differing types by taking a pair of arguments to be used as padding.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the full abstract type 'Tree a' - and the variant of zipWith is somewhat an odd duck.

Comment: @MtnViewMark: It's not possible to define a function for all `Tree a` that has the desired result in brain_damage's example. Note that he wants the strings to be concatenated.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, I just commented on that. I'm pretty sure the OP didn't actually want that - since their preorder and postorder functions don't concatenate the data values.

Comment: I originally wrote the code to do the 'sensible' thing for all `a`, it's a trivial modification. But I thought it would be better to make sure it gave the result actually specified by the asker.

Comment: I wanted strings to be concatenated, just like your first solution. It's beautiful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is homework. On the assumption that it is, then here's some ideas for how to think about the problem that might lead you to an answer:

In `preorder`, first the current item is "reported", then recurse for all this node's tails. In `postorder` these two steps are done in reverse. In both cases, the recursion is "local", in the sense that it only need deal with one node at a time. Is this true for `levelorder`? Or to ask it another way, when `levelorder` recurses, do the results of the recursions interact or no? If so, then, what is the "unit" of recursion, if not a single `Tree`?

Understanding the nature of the recursion (or iteration..?) of `levelorder` will lead you to a solution that very simple and elegant. My version is only three lines long!

By the way, it might be nice to have these utility functions to make the code even clearer in some places:

```
element :: Tree a -> a
element (Nd x _) = x
subtrees :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
subtrees (Nd _ s) = s
```

Or, if you are familiar with record syntax in Haskell, you can achieve exactly this by changing your original `Tree` definition to:

```
data Tree a = Nd { element :: a, subtrees :: [Tree a] }
    deriving Show
```

---

**A full solution:**

The key is realizing that `levelorder` requires recursion on a list of `Tree`. At each step the elements from each `Tree` is extracted, and the next step is upon the concatenation of the subtrees:

```
levelorder :: Tree a -> [a]
levelorder t = step [t]
    where step [] = []
          step ts = map element ts ++ step (concatMap subtrees ts)
```

This produces the elements in a single, flattened list, much like `preorder` and `postorder` do, and is the usual definition of a breadth-first traversal.

If instead you really want the elements grouped by level, a single change of the `++` operator to `:` will yield that version:

```
bylevel :: Tree a -> [[a]]
bylevel t = step [t]
    where step [] = []
          step ts = map element ts : step (concatMap subtrees ts)
```

Note: I have given type signatures for all top-level functions. This is a really good habit to get into, and will save you considerable time debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
levels :: (Tree a) -> [[a]]
levels (Nd x ts) = [[x]] ++ levelshelper ts

level2 = (map concat).levels

levelshelper :: [Tree a] -> [[a]]
levelshelper [] = []
levelshelper xs = (map (\(Nd x ts) -> x) xs) : (levelshelper (extractl xs))

--get the next level's Nd's 
extractl :: [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
extractl [] = []
extractl ((Nd x ts):xs) = ts ++ (extractl xs)
```

My approach turned out being  a bit more ham-handed than I wanted.  Correct me if I'm wrong, though, since strings are lists of characters, but you're using polymorphic types, is it really so straightforward to to print your results out like specified in the problem?  This code produces lists of lists of strings.  ***Props to Chris in his more elegant answer for reminding me about the use of concat!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version which can be applied to `Tree a` instead of `Tree [a]`.

```
levelorder :: Tree a -> [[a]]
levelorder (Nd x ts) = [x]:(ziplist (map levelorder ts))

ziplist :: [[[a]]] -> [[a]]
ziplist l = if null ls then [] else (concat heads):(ziplist tails)
    where
        ls = filter (not.null) l
        heads = map head ls
        tails = map tail ls
```

If you want to concatenate the strings at the end you may use:

```
levelorder2 :: Tree [a] -> [[a]]
levelorder2 = (map concat).levelorder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat [] for empty list so that you don't get the problem with zipWith

```
levels :: Tree a -> [[a]]
levels Empty          = repeat []
levels (Branch x l r) = [x] : zipWith (++) (levels l) (levels r)
```